# Why does this C program crash? It compiled fine

Tags: c, arrays

This program compiles fine. When I input a number, it crashes on me. `name.exe has stopped working` But why?

```
int main (void) {
    int arrayMax = 0;

    printf ("How many numbers will be entered?\n");
    scanf ("%i", arrayMax);

    int i;
    double userInput [arrayMax];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C, that your program compiles correctly is *no guarantee at all* that it will also *run* correctly! C gives you great power, which means it's easy to do something "wrong".

Comment: Do you suggest that a "compiling" program should also always work well ? Maybe C is not the right language for you !

Comment: The for loop is commented out because I was trying to figure out why it wasn't working. I couldn't find an exact answer so I came here.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker > of course my comment above was for OP, not you. Our messages crossed each other.

Comment: When building, it can help to read warning messages as well, and if you don't get warning messages from your code, then increase the level to get more warnings.

Comment: I'm not sure which compiler you're using by the way, but both `clang` & `gcc` give a warning on this error with the default flags (ie. `clang test.c -o test`) ... you may want to look into your compiler & warning settings. This is exactly the sort of problem (wrong argument type) a compiler can catch quite easily!

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: The question (according to the title) is why does a program crash if it compiles fine. Although the answer to 'Program crashes when trying to read numbers with scanf' indeed fixes the issue, it does not directly answer the question at hand (IMHO).

Answer (score 5):

```
scanf ("%i", &arrayMax);
```

Do this scan to the address using `&`. You need to pass the address of the variable to which you need to scan the value to. In this case your variable is arrayMax and you need to pass the address of this variable which the `scanf()` expects and in this case you are not doing so and passing 0 which is not the memory location to which you want to scan your value to so you see crash.
Writing to in-valid memory location causes crash.

Comment: It would help to tell the OP *why* this fixes the issue, and why leaving the `&` off caused the crash in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You forget to place `&` operator in the `scanf` argument.

```
scanf ("%i", &arrayMax);  
          // ^Place unary & to specify the location.
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

As such, the compiler cannot determine whether or not the type of each argument passed to it is correct (expect for the type of the first argument, which is explicitly declared as `const char*`).

As a result, the decision is "moved" from compile-time to run-time, and so instead of a compile-time error you might get a run-time error.

For example, in the case of `scanf("%i")`, the function expects the address of an `int` variable.

In your code you are passing the value 0, so `scanf` will first scan user-input, and then attempt to write it at that memory address.

If the memory segment which includes this address does not have *Write* access permission (for example, if the code-section of your program resides at that address), then this attempt will result with a memory access violation during runtime.

You can get it to work correctly by changing `scanf("%i",arrayMax)` to `scanf("%i",&arrayMax)`.